# Getting indices of array elements matching a value

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I've spent a couple of days on the indexing documentation but haven't found what I am looking for.

Consider this:

```
import numpy
fac=numpy.asarray(['a','a','a','b','b','c','c','c'])
f_ind = [x for x in range(len(fac)) if fac[x] == 'c']
```

it returns `[5,6,7]` like I want.  However, it seems like NumPy arrays should have a mechanism for achieving the same thing in a more concise (and efficient?) way.  Boolean arrays might be part of the solution:

```
ba = (fac == 'c')
f_vals = fac[ba]
```

But that only regurgitates the elements of `fac` that equal `'c'` -- not very helpful.

Any suggestions on how to make this happen using NumPy?  Or should I just be happy with what I've got?

Comment: If you are happy with the True/False values of `fac=='c'`, use `np.nonzero` (or `np.where`) to get the indices of the True values.

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to adress this with NumPy, depending on your needs you could use:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> fac = np.asarray(['a','a','a','b','b','c','c','c'])
```

- [`where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

  ```
  >>> np.where(fac == 'c')
  (array([5, 6, 7], dtype=int64),)
  ```
- [`argwhere`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html):

  ```
  >>> np.argwhere(fac == 'c')
  array([[5],
         [6],
         [7]], dtype=int64)
  ```
- [`flatnonzero`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.flatnonzero.html):

  ```
  >>> np.flatnonzero(fac == 'c')
  array([5, 6, 7], dtype=int64)
  ```

Answer (score 0):

The function you are looking for is numpy's where.

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html

```
np.where(fac=='c')
```

Would return a tuple containing an array of indexes that match that value, and the data type.